# Creating an overlay for image on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to have an overlay (of a colored background) that covers the image when you mouse over the image. So far, I have:

```
<div class='wrap'>
<img class='tilesetsmall' src ='images/sample.jpg'>
<p class='example-text'>Overlay Test text </p>
<div class='ontop'></div>
</div>
<div class='wrap'>
<img class='tilesetsmall' src ='images/sample.jpg'>
<p class='example-text'>Overlay Test text </p>
<div class = 'ontop'></div>     
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrap{
  position: relative; 
  width:500px;
  height:500px; 
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;    
}

.ontop{
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50,1);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display:none;

}
.tilesetsmall{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  position: relative;

}
```

and my jquery code I have so far is:

```
$('.wrap').on('mouseenter','.ontop',function(){
    $(this).find('.ontop').fadein(200);
})
.on('mouseleave','.ontop',function(){
    $(this).find('.ontop').stop().fadeOut(200);
})
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong so I may have included more information than necessary. the overlay text is not part of what I'm having difficulty with (it was to simply put text ontop of the image).

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need Js for this

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6wyt/4/)

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
  position: relative; 
  width:500px;
  height:500px; 
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;    
}

.ontop{
    background-color: rgba(50,50,50,1);
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.wrap:hover .ontop {
    opacity:1;
}
.tilesetsmall{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  position: relative;

}
```

However if you need a JQ solution

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrap').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).find('.ontop').fadeIn(200);

  });
      $('.wrap').mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).find('.ontop').fadeOut(200);

  });
});
```

[**JSfiddle Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6wyt/8/)

Comment: is it better to use css than js in this case?

Comment: It's entirely up to you. Obviously the CSS solution will work even with JS being disnabled but if you have other effects going on you might want to incorporate them into the same function. If it's a simple color overlay, I'd go with CSS for preference.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<p>` tags need to inside your `<div class="onTop>` Also in your js, it should be `fadeIn` Heres a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwW3G/) of your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **.bind** instead of **.on** // bind to attach event handler
2. replace **fadein** with **fadeIn** // I is capital in fadein

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Pk8p/3/
here is the fixed code:

```
$('.wrap').bind('mouseenter','.ontop',function(){
    $(this).find('.ontop').fadeIn(200);
})
.bind('mouseleave','.ontop',function(){
    $(this).find('.ontop').stop().fadeOut(200);
})
```

Comment: what is the benefit of using bind instead of on?